# Simple ERC-20 Token Contract Questions

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I have been searching the web for a simple/safe ERC-20 Token Bare-Bone Contract example to use as a base for learning. The Bare-Bones as I understand would only include what the ERC-20 Token Standard requires it to:

```
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
```

*sources:* https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard , https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md

However, even when finding simple templates, you find differences, for instance:

- [Official ethereum.org/token example:](https://www.ethereum.org/token)

includes the `burn(...)` and `burnFrom(...)` functions. At first glance, all that might need to be done is delete these two. However when looking at another example:

- [Github link to a token example:](https://github.com/bitfwdcommunity/Issue-your-own-ERC20-token/blob/master/contracts/erc20_tutorial.sol)

there was the inclusion of various other portions of code that at first glance might seem vital for the ERC-20 standard (but I'm unsure), for instance:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe maths
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

Is the **SafeMaths** section preventing some types of hacks/exploits? And if that were the case, why don't I see something as important as this in other token examples? Also I'm unsure why another contract called `ERC20Interface` is being made that initiates the functions, is it just for organization purposes?

If someone has a better simple BARE-BONES template, please do sure! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ERC20 interface is defined by the contract itself (`ERC20Interface`) and that is the minimum you need to extend to define an `ERC20` token.

`SafeMath` doesn't by itself do any prevention automatically. It is a set of tools for writing safer mathematical operations. For example using `safeAdd` instead of `+` will allow you to prevent numerical overflow.

You can refer to the following tutorial for steps on creating an `ERC20` token:

https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-build-your-own-ethereum-based-erc20-token-and-launch-an-ico-in-next-20-minutes-cjbcpwzec01c93awtbij90uzn

> This article aims to give you an overview of how smart contracts work
>   in Ethereum by launching a simple demo ICO.

Answer (score 1):

Your SafeMaths section is a safety check. It prevents overflows. You can get a good and well tested library from [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol)

OpenZeppelin has also a very good introduction for smart contracts newbies: https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-smart-contracts-in-ethereum-848f08001f05

> I’ve decided to compile a short guide to ease the way of future programmers learning Ethereum smart contract development. I’ve divided the guide in two sections: how to get started building smart contracts in Ethereum, and a quick note on smart contract security.